# Model-View-Controller in iOS

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

I understand Model-View-Controller design pattern: there are three objects, model, view and controller where view does all the drawing, receives user interactions and reports back to controller. However, in iOS, you have `UIViewController`, which is a controller with a view as one object and all drawing and processing are to be done in the same object, wouldn't that violate the MVC pattern? Shouldn't you create a separate UIView object and link it to a separate controller object?

It would be great if anyone could help me clear this up. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about what you mean, but the View Controller's `.view` can have subviews (so it doesn't have to do all the drawing itself). Note Apple's MVC pattern is a little bit different from the standard MVC.

Comment: And note that there is a separate View and Controller: `UIViewController` has a property `view` which holds the view object.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers! `UIViewController` has its own `view` but lets say, you have to draw a button on to that view, doesn't that happen in the `UIViewController` object itself? Whereas if you have a separate `UIView` object, controller can call `[separateView showButton]` and let `separateView` does drawing? Unless you are meant to create a new `UIView` object and tell `UIViewController`'s `view` to add that separate view as a subview, is that the way it suppose to be?

Comment: Yes, you should do something like `[self.view addSubview:[[MyButtonView alloc] initWithTarget:self andSelector:@selector(...)]];`. If that is what you meant, I'll write a proper answer.

Comment: I think that is what I am looking for, can you write up a proper answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view can have subviews, so a view controller can add subviews to its main view, like this:

```
[self.view addSubview:[[MyNSViewSubclass alloc] initWith...]];
```

Though you'd normally do this with InterfaceBuilder.

So one view controller is responsible for its main view (`.view`) *and its subviews*.

Every view implements the `-drawRect:` method, the controller shouldn't know anything about the drawing of its views.

In some scenarios you have multiple view controllers as well (think UINavigationController's navigation stack) with each their own main view.

### Update

It depends. A view could of course do `[self addSubview:...];` as well. If you want to construct the interface programmatically, I would do this from the view controller. If you design a custom view and you notice it can reuse existing views, you should add these existing views as subviews inside your custom view class. Adding and removing top level views (I mean direct children of the view controller's `.view`) should IMHO be done from the view controller. (Because the controller is responsible for getting its view to represent the model, it should do so even if it takes adding/removing subviews.)

It depends. Do as much as possible with Interface Builder, otherwise, let common sense decide.

Comment: That is actually not quite what I meant. If you have `separateView=[MyNSViewSubclass alloc] initWith...]` and then `[self.view addSubview:separateView]`, is the 'View' in Model View Controller now `separateView` or is it still `UIViewController`'s `view`? And also, when I said "drawing" I meant creating and adding a button to the view, that's the view's job in MVC right?

Comment: Ah, I understand what you mean. Let me update my answer. @user945711

Comment: Yes, thank you. Seems like I have misunderstood the MVC pattern, I thought the view is supposed to create the button itself, the button's title is set by the controller and it reports the button pressed event to the controller. I am not a big fan of the Interface Builder so I usually code all the view components.

Comment: @user945711 I think learning to use Interface Builder will be a great benefit; it completely takes away this problem.

Comment: It is actually no problem, I have got everything working just fine, I just did not understand why this does not violate the MVC pattern. I prefer coding over Interface Builder because of its flexibility, or maybe it's just me. Thanks for clearing this up for me anyway!